# Dataflow pipeline failed - "Unknown"

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

One of our Dataflow pipelines failed with the following error ("unknown") when trying to write to BigQuery.

Any ideas as to what went wrong?

id: **2015-12-03_08_15_37-6773615943090215874**

```
Dec 4, 2015, 5:29:40 AM
S41: (83c82aae36b3b348): Workflow failed. Causes: (83c82aae36b3bcd7): BigQuery import job "dataflow_job_6773615943090212934" failed. Causes: (83c82aae36b3b666): BigQuery getting job "dataflow_job_6773615943090212934" in project "<removed>" failed. Causes: (83c82aae36b3bff5): BigQuery execution failed. caused by: (83c82aae36b3b984): Unknown error.
```

[image]

Comment: Quick note: the "refusing to split" message is not an error (it's a routine part of dynamic work rebalancing) and not related to the failure of the job, which was ultimately caused by a failed BigQuery import.

Comment: @jkff - thanks, post updated to reflect

Comment: Looking into it now, thanks for your patience.

Comment: We've noticed the import jobs to BigQuery on all of our pipelines are taking much longer than usual. Another example: 2015-12-03_15_23_32-2105010438944471895

Comment: For the first issue, we've tracked it down to an error handling bug.  Looking into the more general slowdown now.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but our latest pipeline to run took almost double the time to complete. Job dataflowpipeline-cdf-1203233753 took 2hr 10min. A subsequent job, dataflowpipeline-cdf-1204034654, with the exact same settings took 3hr 58min. Same VMs, same data etc.

Comment: Note the bigquery job failed with a not_found error on a missing GCS file. Perhaps dataflow had given up and already cleaned up the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This failure was caused by early deletion of the files based on a failure code returned from BigQuery.  Similarly to [Dataflow job failed - BigQuery import job not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096721/dataflow-job-failed-bigquery-import-job-not-found), we're actively pursuing a fix.

UPDATE: This issue is now fixed.